# How do Vim's Control-O and Control-I work?

Tags: vim, keyboard-shortcuts

What do they do, and how do you use them? Any tips / tricks would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 158, accepted):

In insert mode, `Ctrl-o` escapes user to do one normal-mode command, and then return to the insert mode. The same effect can be achieved by `<ESC>`ing to normal mode, doing the single command and then entering back to insert mode. `Ctrl-i` is simply a `<Tab>` in insert mode.

In normal mode, `Ctrl-o` and `Ctrl-i` jump user through their "jump list", a list of places where your cursor has been to. The jumplist can be used with the quickfix feature, for example to quickly enter to a line of code containing errors.

Comment: See also the help on the jump list (`:h jumplist`) in vim.

Comment: It might be worth nothing that `<C-o>`, `<C-O`, and `<C-i>` `<C-I>` seem to have identical results.  Saves your ring finger from having to hold the Shift key.

Comment: @J.M.Janzen It's deeper than that. Most shells don't differentiate between "lowercase" and "capital" control characters, so Vim, which was designed to run in a terminal shell, doesn't either. In most shells, it couldn't if it tried.

Comment: More to the point, there is no such thing as a "capital" (or "lowercase") control character - there is nothing to differentiate. Conventional ASCII control characters are their own bank of 32 code points (0x00 to 0x1f - they all have proper 2-3 character names, like NUL, BEL, and CR), the normal convention is to write them in uppercase (originally, the style `^A`, `^B`, `^C`, etc., was used), because uppercase letters are more easily distinguished, but that *never* means to hold down the shift key while entering a control character.

Comment: A genuine example where vim doesn't differentiate is <C-W> s and <C-W> S, which do the same thing (the latter S is not a control character), and also <C-W> <C-S> also does the same. (Horizontal split.)

Comment: I can't find the documentation for `<C-O>`. Edit: Found it. See `:h i_CTRL-O`.